# GIT extensions how to replace a file and not merge.

Tags: git-extensions

i am a college student working on a game in a group. we are using git extensions with windows studio 10. we are programming in c# using xna frame work. it's been going just fine however yesterday when i tried to pull the latest version, it told me that a few of our .wma files had conflicts. in the bin/x86/... directory. i wish to completely replace the offending files on my local repository with the ones from the online repository. instead git extensions wants to resolve the conflicts with kdiff. can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

In the Resolve merge conflicts window, it should show a list of files with conflicts.
Right-click on the file you want to replace and pick `Choose remote (theirs)`.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  Works perfectly.  No need to drop down into Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated question (for git), and there's no simple way to resolve this within GitExtensions. It just doesn't give you that feature.

You'll need to go on bash (which Git Extensions have a button to) and [type in stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git).

In my similar case, something like this helped a lot:

```
> git pull
(merge state)
> git checkout --ours .
> git add .
> git commit -m "merge using ours"
```